# try to buffer overflow value allocated by malloc()

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I'm a bit confused about malloc() function.

if `sizeof(char)` is **1** `byte` and the `malloc()` function accepts N bytes in argument to allocate, then if I do:

```
char* buffer = malloc(3);
```

I allocate a buffer that can to store 3 characters, right?

```
char* s = malloc(3);
int i = 0;
while(i < 1024) { s[i] = 'b'; i++; }
s[i++] = '$';
s[i] = '\0';
printf("%s\n",s);
```

it works fine. and stores 1024 `b's` in `s`.

```
bbbb[...]$
```

why doesn't the code above cause a buffer overflow? Can anyone explain?

Comment: Fix the bug and the mystery will go away. Buggy code does strange things, that's why we don't write buggy code.

Comment: This *is* a buffer overflow; you're just not doing anything to exploit it. C will happily let you write to a memory address, as long as it actually exists. This is not rocket science.

Comment: @tbert "as long as it actually exists" isn't strictly true - if it's outside the address space of your process, C won't let you write to it.

Comment: @TimothyJones okay, "actually exists within your VM space"; I'm not sure that we need to be that pedantic, given the confused nature of the question itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`malloc(size)` returns a location in memory where at least `size` bytes are available for you to use. You are likely to be able to write to the bytes immediately after `s[size]`, but:

- Those bytes may belong to other bits of your program, which will cause problems later in the execution.
- Or, the bytes might be fine for you to write to - they might belong to a page your program uses, but aren't used for anything.
- Or, they might belong to the structures that `malloc()` has used to keep track of what your program has used. Corrupting this is very bad!
- Or, they might NOT belong to your program, which will result in an immediate segmentation fault. This is likely if you access say `s[size + large_number]`

It's difficult to say which one of these will happen because **accessing outside the space you asked `malloc()` for will result in undefined behaviour.**

In your example, **you are overflowing the buffer**, but not in a way that causes an immediate crash. Keep in mind that C does no bounds checking on array/pointer accesses.

---

Also, `malloc()` creates memory on the heap, but buffer overflows are usually about memory on the stack. If you want to create one as an exercise, use

```
char s[3];
```

instead. This will create an array of 3 chars on the stack. On most systems, there won't be any free space after the array, and so the space after `s[2]` will belong to the stack. Writing to that space can overwrite other variables on the stack, and ultimately cause segmentation faults by (say) overwriting the current stack frame's return pointer.

---

One other thing:

> if `sizeof(char)` is 1 byte

`sizeof(char)` is actually defined by the standard to always be 1 byte. However, the size of that 1 byte might not be 8 bits on exotic systems. Of course, most of the time you don't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 1):

It is **Undefined Behavior(UB)** to write beyond the bounds of allocated memory.

Any behavior is possible, no diagnostic is needed for UB & any behavior can be encountered.
An UB does not necessarily warrant a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

In a way, you did overflow your 3 character buffer. However, you did not overflow your program's address space (yet). So you are well out of the bounds of s*, but you are overwriting random other data in your program. Because your program owns this data, the program doesn't crash, but still does very very wrong things, and the future behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

In practice what this is doing is corrupting the heap.  The effects may not appear immediately (in fact, that's part of what makes such errors a PITA to debug).  However, you may trash anything else that happens to be in the heap, or in that part of your program's address space for that matter.  It's likely that you have also trashed `malloc()` internal data structures, and so it's likely that subsequent `malloc()` or `free()` calls may crash your program, leading many programmers to (falsely) believe they've found a bug in `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're overflowing the buffer. It depends what memory you're overflowing into to get an error msg.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try executing your code in release mode or did you try to free up the memory you of s? It is an undefined behavior.

It's a bit of a language hack, and a bit dubious about it's use.